# Route that automatically gets name from webapi action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have ApiController that looks like

```
[RoutePrefix("Companies")]
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("GetCompanyProfile")]
  public GetProfileOutput GetCompanyProfile()
  {
     // some code
  }
}
```

Now, if I try to simplify the code so that I dont have to specify the route name explicitely, but instead reuse the action function name, it looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("Companies")]
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
  [Route, HttpGet]
  public GetProfileOutput GetCompanyProfile()
  {
     // some code
  }
}
```

But now, the GetCompanyProfile action is not any longer recognized.

What is my code actually doing? Is there a way to have the route name automatically fetched from the action name?

Comment: Try using `[Route(Companies)]` on your class, and then just don't include the Route attribute on the method, i.e. just `[HttpGet]`

Comment: Can you show us how you mapped your routes inside `RegisterRoutes`?

Comment: In `Global.asax.cs`, I use `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[Route("Companies/[action]")]
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
   public GetProfileOutput GetCompanyProfile()
  {
     // some code
  }
}
```

but  if it is possible change controller name to CompaniesController. In this case you will not need an attribute routing